# Question about Ryobi P261 Impact Wrench Torque

Tags: torque

I am planning to buy this Impact Wrench:

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Ryobi-ONE-18-Volt-1-2-in-Cordless-3-Speed-Impact-Wrench-Tool-Only-P261/205885687

This Impact Wrench has 3 speeds:

0-2,900 RPM for maximum torque (no load speed)
0-2,300 RPM for controlling driving depth and fastener tension (no load speed)
0-1,800 RPM for precision fastening (no load speed)

At the highest speed, it produces 300 ft. lbs.

What is its torque at the lower speeds (2300 and 2800 RPM) ?

Comment: I cannot find any "specifics" on this, but watched this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/TXu-4qiNqWw?t=5m25s) about the 1/2" model (same thing only 1/2" drive). The torque is governed at 300 lb-ft at the top speed, with the 1st and 2nd speeds producing *less* torque (as shown in the video). Unlike a lot of other cordless power tools, it doesn't have gear reduction, but rather relies on the motor for it's speed differential. I would suspect the switch actually limits the amount of power going to the motor, which then limits the speed accordingly.

Comment: I wonder if there is formula that converts RPM to torque?